# Exporting Flash Movie with Dynamic Text - no text showing

Tags: flash, flash-cs5

(Using Flash CS5 on Windows)

I've created a very simple FLA/SWF that does exactly what I want it to do in native formats - it has 600 frames at 1fps, a keyframe at the start sets up a dynamic text box; a script that sets a timer every second and counts down from 10:00 to 0:00; and also sets a 10m music track playing. I have a keyframe at the final second (as before I did this it only exported as a 1s movie).

This works great giving me a little movie with an audio track that counts down ten minutes.

Trouble is, ANY attempt to convert this to MP4, AVI, WMV etc results in a ten minute black screen with the audio playing but no text displayed at all. The font I am using is OCR A Std and I chose to embed the numerics and punctuation. Obviously the text for any given second is being set by changing the .text property of the dynamic text box.

What do I need to do to get the movie to export correctly?

TIA, M

Comment: Flash exports any video format (or animated GIF, or PNG sequence) with no regard to any scripts. Basically, it exports all that you can see in design mode if you press ENTER to play the timeline.

Comment: Export to SWF is fine, it's when I do any kind of conversion from that or native export to video format that the text does not appear at all...

Comment: That's what I said above. All scripts are ignored while exporting to video or image formats. You cannot export a scripted output to a video via Flash Publish.